# Setting up a remote mail server

Tags: home-server, mail-server, dynamic-ip

I have an Ubuntu server running at a remote location which I log into with putty My dynamic ip is maintained using a NoIP account.

I am trying to learn about php dynamic websites and as a result I also connect to this remote server using core ftp and an ftp connection from a copy of Dreamweaver Studio8.

It's taken a while but I appear to have e-mail working from a "telnet local host 25" and now my web page contact appears to be working.

However when I looked at my mail queue using mailq I have four refused e-mails from the dynamic assigned IP.

When I followed this up I found the IP was sometimes blocked by Spamhaus PBL and investigation suggested I set up a smarthost through my isp but the server is on one isp and my home account and target for my mail is another so which isp do I use?

The infuriating thing is at most the out going e-mail will go to one of three addresses and even then only one at any one time I would realy like to be able to say this Domain name with associated ip address can mail to this e-mail adddress so that this cannot be hijacked by spammers.

So a second question is if this is possible how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I have an Ubuntu server running at a remote location

Is this another "home" location? Dynamic IPs are usually assigned only by residential ISPs, business ISPs or web service providers can usually give you a static IP.

> but the server is on one isp and my home account and target for my mail is another so which isp do I use?

For all mail originating from the server, if it has a dynamic IP it should be using that ISP' SMTP server.